# Assign value to a variable in bash, coming from another commands

Tags: bash, variable

Doing this in bash, makes SUFFIX variable holding /dev/fd/[fd],

```
SUFFIX=<( echo "&*645\[]}#@name" | sed -r 's/[^[:alnum:]]+/_/g' )
```

What should I do to assign the actual result, of commands being executed in between parenthesis? So in this case SUFFIX should be assigned a value of `_645_name`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've used the syntax for [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), which passes the output of a command as input to another command. But what you wanted was [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution), which grabs the output of a command as a string. Command substitution uses `$(…)`.

```
SUFFIX=$( echo "&*645\[]}#@name" | sed -r 's/[^[:alnum:]]+/_/g' )
```

Note that if you're using bash, you can do this with its own built-in constructs. If the text to sanitize is in the variable `foo`:

```
shopt -s extglob
SUFFIX=${foo//+([^[:alnum:]])/_}
```

Comment: Great! I was just about to ask for a builtin equivalent of doing the same thing, which of course is much more efficient and less dependent on other external commands. Thanks.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: @branquito That's a completely different question. Please don't ask unrelated questions together. (But to save you a trip, the answer is `"outfile-" ENVIRON["SUFFIX"] ".txt"` — there's no interpolation in awk strings, but juxtaposition is concatenation.)

Answer (score 2):

If that's your suffix the answer should be this easy:

```
suffix="${str##*[!_A-Za-z0-9]}"
```

To get the pieces with this method you can at most ever get head and tail. But you can get those:

```
head="${str%"${tail:="${str##*[!_A-Za-z0-9]"}"}"}"
```